# Git Hook access to Merge Conflicts

Tags: java, git, maven, hook

I know I am not the first person to have this problem, but I could not find an answer for what I am looking for. I am familiar with Git, but new to Git hooks.

## Problem:

I have a Git repo that is made up of several Java modules using Maven to build the artifacts.  In the "master/main" branch the version number is always `Major.Minor.Patch.Build-SNAPSHOT`, until a release is made then the `-SNAPSHOT` is dropped and the artifact is created. Then the correct version number(s) are incremented to the next version and `-SNAPSHOT` is added back in.  Each night there is a nightly build that will increment the Build version number; and based on Semantic Versioning the `Major.Minor.Patch` versions will be updated based on Pull Request merges. So, the POM version will be changing daily in different ways.

When a developer creates a branch off of "master/main", we want to write a Git hook to change the POM version to `Major.Minor.Patch.Build-DEV-QUALIFIER-SNAPSHOT`. I have figured out where to do that with the `post-checkout` Git hook. And have written a generic version validation shell script to be used.

When a developer merges the latest from "master/main" into their branch, this will create a conflict. I can use the `pre-merge-commit` hook to do a `git checkout --theirs [PATH TO POM FILE]`; and then call the version validation script to change the POM versions. I believe there is a hook to do the same thing for rebases. And possibly one for both rebase and merge. `post-rewrite`?

Here is where the problem starts to come into play....
What happens when a developer makes a change to the POM file (ex - adds a new dependency)?  Every time they do a merge/rebase; they would loose their changes and have to add those changes back in.

## Question:

Since there will always be a merge conflict with the POM files, is there an easy way to automate the conflicts coming in from "master/main"? Using the new POM version, but keeping the changes the developer has made at the same time?

---

Or, is the best way to read in the POM file which will have a conflict that looks like:

```
<<<<<<<< HEAD
<version>1.2.3.4-Dev-Qualifier-SNAPSHOT</version>
=======
<version>1.2.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
>>>>>>> master/main
```

and remove:

```
<<<<<<<< HEAD
<version>1.2.3.4-Dev-Qualifier-SNAPSHOT</version>
=======
>>>>>>> master/main
```

Leaving

```
<version>1.2.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

in place?

---

Or do we tell the developer to resolve any conflicts and then use the `pre-commit` hook to validate the POM versions.

---

Are there any libraries that will do all of this?  Like I mentioned earlier, I know I am not the first person to face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about Git Hooks.  If there is a conflict from a merge, or rebase, the Git Hooks will not be called. This means there is no way to automatically resolve conflicts from merges, or rebases.  Conflicts must always be done manually.

There is a way to validate the version in the POM files are correct by using the pre-commit, or pre-push, hooks.  Though using pre-commit will execute on every `git commit`.  `pre-push` may be the way to go if version validation is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it through a custom merge driver. Every time there is a merge conflict, your custom merge driver will be called. So the only thing you have to do is implement such a driver for combining POMs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).